# Where can I find blueprints for the Wright Model HS?

Tags: aircraft-design, aviation-history

I'm looking for the Wright Model HS blueprints. Can someone help me?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to reach out to the [national archives](https://www.archives.gov/) they seem to have at least some of the [Wright Brothers Blueprints](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/lost-plans-for-wright-brothers-flying-machine-found-after-36-years/2016/04/02/e526fd56-f6b2-11e5-9804-537defcc3cf6_story.html?utm_term=.da72867538e4). The [Smithsonian](https://airandspace.si.edu/) may also be of help as [they seem to have some stuff of theirs as well.](https://airandspace.si.edu/files/pdf/archives/wright-brothers.pdf) This organization also has some of [their early plans and seems to be knowledgeable on the topic](http://www.wright-brothers.org/Information_Desk/Information_Intro/Information_Intro.htm) you may want to reach out to them.